# Consequences of updating other key(s) in ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

Javadoc from `ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent` says

> The computation should be short and simple, and must not attempt to
>   update any other mappings of this map.

But, from what I see, using `remove()` and `clear()` methods inside `mappingFunction` works fine. For example this

```
Key element = elements.computeIfAbsent(key, e -> {
    if (usages.size() == maxSize) {
        elements.remove(oldest);
    }
    return loader.load(key);
});
```

What bad consequences of using remove() method inside `mappingFunction` could be?

Comment: Such a spec should be read very carefully. The words "must not attempt" indicate that you probably break something somewhere if you don't follow the rule. But in comparism to Andy I am always really interested in why such restrictions are put in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc explains clearly the cause :

> **Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be**
>   **blocked while computation is in progress**, so the computation should be
>   short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of
>   this map.

You have not to forget that `ConcurrentHashMap` is designed to provide a way of using a thread safe Map without being as locking as it is the case for older thread safe Map classes as `HashTable`.
When a modification on the map occurs, it locks only the concerned mapping and not the whole map.

> `ConcurrentHashMap` is a hash table supporting full concurrency of
>   retrievals and high expected concurrency for updates.

`computeIfAbsent()` is a new method added in Java 8.
If badly used, that is, if in the body of `computeIfAbsent()` that already locks the mapping of the key passed to the method,  you lock another key, you enter in a path where you may defeat the purpose of the `ConcurrentHashMap` as finally you will lock two mapping.
Imagine the problem if you lock more mapping inside `computeIfAbsent()` and that the method is not short at all. Concurrency access on the map would become slow.

So the javadoc of `computeIfAbsent()` stresses on this potential issue by reminding the principles of `ConcurrentHashMap` :  keep it simple and fast.

---

Here is example code illustrating the issue.
Suppose we have an instance of `ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>`.

We will start two threads that use it :

- The first thread : `thread1` that invokes `computeIfAbsent()` with the key `1`
- The second thread : `thread2` that invokes `computeIfAbsent()` with the key `2`

`thread1` executes a fast enough task but it doesn't follow advise of the `computeIfAbsent()` javadoc : it updates the key `2` in `computeIfAbsent()`, that is another mapping of which one used in the current context of the method (that is key `1`). 

`thread2` executes a long enough task. It invokes `computeIfAbsent()` with the key `2` by following advises of the javadoc : it doesn't update any other mapping in the implementation of it.
To simulate the long task, we can use the `Thread.sleep()` method with `5000` as parameter.
For this specific situation, if `thread2` starts before `thread1`, the invocation of`map.put(2, someValue);` in `thread1` will be blocked while `thread2` is not returned of `computeIfAbsent()` that locks the mapping of the key `2`.

Finally, we get a `ConcurrentHashMap` instance that blocks the mapping of the key `2` during 5 seconds while `computeIfAbsent()` is invoked with the mapping of the key `1`.
It is misleading, not effective and it goes against the `ConcurrentHashMap` intention and the `computeIfAbsent()` description which the intention is computing the value for the current key :

> if the specified key is not already associated with a value, attempts
>   to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it
>   into this map unless null

The sample code :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class BlockingCallOfComputeIfAbsentWithConcurrentHashMap {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            map.computeIfAbsent(1, e -> {
                String valueForKey2 = map.get(2);
                System.out.println("thread1 : get() returns with value for key 2 = " + valueForKey2);
                String oldValueForKey2 = map.put(2, "newValue");
                System.out.println("thread1 : after put() returns, previous value for key 2 = " + oldValueForKey2);
                return map.get(2);
            });
        }
    };

    Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          map.computeIfAbsent(2, e -> {
            try {
              Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
              e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String value = "valueSetByThread2";
            System.out.println("thread2 : computeIfAbsent() returns with value for key 2 = " + value);
            return value;
          });
        }
    };

    thread2.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    thread1.start();
  }
}
```

As output we always get :

> thread1 : get() returns with value for key 2 = null
>
> thread2 : computeIfAbsent() returns with value for key 2 =
>   valueSetByThread2
>
> thread1 : after put() returns, previous value for key 2 =
>   valueSetByThread2

This is written fast as reads on the `ConcurrentHashMap` are not blocking :

> thread1 : get() returns with value for key 2 = null

but this :

> thread1 : after put() returns, previous value for key 2 =
>   valueSetByThread2

is output only when thread2 is returned of `computeIfAbsent()`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example of a bad consequence:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<Integer,String> cmap = new ConcurrentHashMap<> ();
cmap.computeIfAbsent (1, e-> {cmap.remove (1); return "x";});
```

This code causes a deadlock.

Comment: it *used* to cause a deadlock; not anymore: *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive update*

Answer (score 2):

Such advice is a bit like the advice not to walk down the middle of a road. You can do it, and you may well not be hit by a car; you may also be able to get out of the way if you see the car coming.

However, you'd have been safer if you'd just stayed on the pavement (sidewalk) in the first place.

If an API document tells you not to do something, there is of course nothing stopping you from doing it. And you might try doing it, and find that there are no ill consequences, at least in the limited circumstances that you test. You can even dig in to find out the exact reasons why the advice is there; you can scrutinize the source code and prove that it is safe in your use case.

However, the implementors of the API are free to change the implementation, within the constraints of the contract described by the API documentation. They might make a change that stops your code working tomorrow, because they are under no obligation to preserve behavior that they explicitly warn against using.

So, to answer your question of what the bad consequences could be: literally anything (well, anything that completes normally or throws a `RuntimeException`); and you would not necessarily observe the same consequences over time or on different JVMs.

Stay on the pavement: don't do what the documentation tells you not to.