# ConcurrentHashMap throws IllegalStateException: Recursive update

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

First of all, I am aware of several similar ([53998845](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53998845), [71087512](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087512), [71269113](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71269113)) and related ([28840047](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28840047), [44224952](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44224952)) questions, but I believe that none of them exactly captures the same situation that I am encountering.

I am using a `ConcurrentHashMap` as a cache for some runtime-generated Java classes. Specifically, I use `computeIfAbsent` to either return a previously generated class, or generate the class on the fly. In some circumstances, this call throws an `IllegalStateException: Recursive update`. An example stack trace looks like this:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Recursive update
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1742)
at pro.projo.internal.rcg.RuntimeCodeGenerationHandler.getImplementationOf(RuntimeCodeGenerationHandler.java:151)
at pro.projo.Projo.getImplementationClass(Projo.java:451)
at pro.projo.Projo.getImplementationClass(Projo.java:438)
at fxxx.natives.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.lambda$configure$2(Bootstrap.java:63)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1510)
at fxxx.natives.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.configure(Bootstrap.java:76)
at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:66)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:409)
at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:108)
at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:160)
at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:107)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
at fxxx.natives.bootstrap.Bootstrap.<init>(Bootstrap.java:89)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:782)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:724)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1396)
at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.findFirst(ServiceLoader.java:1811)
at fxxx.bootstrap.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:34)
at fxxx.test.junit.FxxxTestClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(FxxxTestClassTestDescriptor.java:27)
```

As far as I am aware, I am not violating `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent`'s requirement that "*The mapping function must not modify this map during computation*", as that function is a pure function without side effects.
For the other requirement, that "*the computation should be short and simple*", my code's compliance is not as clear cut, since generating the classes on the fly is definitely an involved and expensive process (hence the caching).

I do, however, believe that the exception's claimed "*Recursive update*" is an incorrect assessment of what is actually going on here. If that were indeed the case, I would expect to see multiple occurrences of my code's call to `CHM.computeIfAbsent` in the stack trace, but this is not what I see (not in the example stack trace, or any other stack trace that I've seen with this problem).

The code in `CHM` is as follows:

```
1738            Node<K,V> pred = e;
1739            if ((e = e.next) == null) {
1740                if ((val = mappingFunction.apply(key)) != null) {
1741                    if (pred.next != null)
1742                        throw new IllegalStateException("Recursive update");
1743                    added = true;
1744                    pred.next = new Node<K,V>(h, key, val);
1745                }
1746                break;
1747            }
```

From the stack trace, I already know that this is not a recursive call to `computeIfAbsent` from within another `computeIfAbsent` invocation. The code saves a reference to the previous node as `pred` (line 1738) and then updates `e` to the next node (line 1739). Since we made it past the `if` check, we know that the original `e`'s `next` value was `null`, therefore `pred.next` should at this point also be `null`.
However, a subsequent check (line 1741) reveals that `pred` next is no longer `null` (which triggers the exception).
As a *recursive* update is not corroborated by the stack trace, I am assuming that this must actually be a *concurrent* update instead. It appears that the original `e` object, now known as `pred`, has its `next` pointer changed by another thread (`java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.Node` produces mutable objects, unfortunately).

I am using `CHM` for the one reason that this caching mechanism must be thread-safe and have low overhead (i.e., no blanket locking). I would expect concurrent update of the cache to work. However, in this particular scenario, *concurrent* access does *not* work, and seems to be incorrectly classified as a *recursive* update instead.

For further context, my own code that invokes `computeIfAbsent` looks like this:

```
public Class<? extends _Artifact_> getImplementationOf(Class<_Artifact_> type, boolean defaultPackage)
{
    return implementationClassCache.computeIfAbsent(type, it -> generateImplementation(it, defaultPackage));
}
```

This code is from a utility library that needs to work on Java 8, but I've only ever seen the exception happen when the code is used from another project that's running on Java 11.

Is this another bug in `ConcurrentHashMap` or am I overlooking something regarding the proper use of this class?

Comment: The crucial method here is `generateImplementation`, which clearly (as that's what the error means) somehow results in you calling `put`, or `computeIfAbsent`, or therefore this very `getImplementationOf` method. It's possible it's not and there is a bug in CHM< but that is an extraordinary claim that requires extraordinary evidence. At the very least, that evidence would have to include the code of `generateImplementation`. Without it, I'm going with the 99% bet, which is, that generateImpl modifies the map.

Comment: In this instance, _recursive_ means that a thread performed a write operation while inside the scope of another write operation, to the same map instance. This assertion only occurs under the hash bin's exclusive lock, which a writer must acquire before it can proceed. Therefore unless this rule was violated by its author, the only thread that could trigger this assertion is one that held the lock previously from a write earlier on its call stack. The workaround is to compute [outside](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Faq#recursive-computations) of the mapping operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, mea culpa, false alarm, after some further debugging it turns out that `ConcurrentHashMap` works as designed. There was a rarely executed code branch, where the runtime code generator made use of itself to create certain classes (I should have foreseen that this would cause trouble at some point). The problem only surfaced when the particular class was not in the cache yet, i.e. there was a *recursive* call but no *update*, which made it look like a race condition (which it technically was).

My fallacy when analyzing the stack traces was that the offending update (of course!) had already popped of the stack since it already had already been completed. The first update (which caused the problem) succeeded just fine, but it was the second update that threw the exception, and, by then, the offending earlier update was no longer on the stack.

The way I tracked it down in the end was by using an instrumented anonymous subclass of `CHM`. Instead of just initializing the map with `new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<_Artifact_>, Class<? extends _Artifact_>>();`, I used:

```
new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<_Artifact_>, Class<? extends _Artifact_>>()
{
    @Override
    public Class<? extends _Artifact_> computeIfAbsent(Class<_Artifact_> key, Function<? super Class<_Artifact_>, ? extends Class<? extends _Artifact_>> mappingFunction)
    {
        Stream<StackTraceElement> stack = Stream.of(new Throwable().getStackTrace());
        if (stack.filter(element -> element.getMethodName().equals("computeIfAbsent")).count() > 2)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("recursive update happening!");
        }
        return super.computeIfAbsent(key, mappingFunction);
    }   
};
```

Normally, there should only be two occurrences of `computeIfAbsent` in the stack (one for the modified implementation in the subclass, and one for the original implementation called via `super`). If there were more than two, this means there was a recursive update (unless there happened to be multiple different maps involved). This pinpointed the source of the problem pretty quickly, and I thought it might be worth sharing (alternatively, some debuggers may have a feature that can be used to the same effect).

Answer (score 1):

### ConcurrentHashmap - computeIfAbsent

**Throws:**
IllegalStateException – if the computation detectably attempts a recursive update to this map that would otherwise never complete

---

Diving into the ConcurrentHashmap class file, the following code triggers the IllegalStateException.

```
    Node<K,V> pred = e;
    if ((e = e.next) == null) {
        if ((val = mappingFunction.apply(key)) != null) {
            if (pred.next != null)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Recursive update");
            added = true;
            pred.next = new Node<K,V>(h, key, val);
        }
        break;
    }
```

We can see it throws the exception when the mapping function has altered the HashMap making the last node have a new node which it didn't just before in the `(e = e.next) == null` check.

Comment: My original post contains pretty much the same analysis already (except that I was mistakenly disputing that there actually was a recursive update, and blamed it on a concurrent update instead). So, unfortunately, this answer didn't help much in my particular case.